# Angular - cant access assets from component (error 404)

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I have problem when I'm trying to access file from assets directory.

I'm trying to serve an image from navbar component which is located in components/navbar. Image is located in assets/img directory.

```
Browser throws an error http://localhost:4200/assets/img/test.png (404) not found
```

I'm using angular 5,Angular CLI 1.5 and Node: 6.10.3

Here you can see code and project structure.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nugho.png)

navbar.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">No Name</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a routerLink="#">Pitanja<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="#">Oznake</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="isLoggedIn == true">
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{user.username}} <span class="caret"></span></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a routerLink="/user/{{user.username}}">My profile</a></li>
                  <li><a routerLink="#">Settings</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a routerLink="#" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" *ngIf="isLoggedIn == false">
            <li><a routerLink="/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a routerLink="/register">Register</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
<img src="assets/img/test.png" />
```

Comment: Could you please show your relevant code so that we can know what is not working? Instead of posting a screenshot , it is better to include the code in your post.

Comment: @edkeveked check it again, post is updated, if you want to see project structure check screnshoot up there

Comment: in MEAN stack, assets folder could be placed anywhere depending on the grunt file or template setting. are you using grunt?

Comment: Did you include your asset/img path in "assets' property in .angular cli?

Comment: @realharry yes I did, you can check it here https://pastebin.com/npPA10bv

Comment: @JosipReh Yes. One thing you can do is, try `ng build` and see under the "dist" folder to check if the image is actually being copied.

Comment: @realharry no it's not.

Comment: OK, there is a good clue. Your angular cli file looks good to me. So, why isn't the image being copied? Try putting the image at the src root and add it explicitly into the angular cli file, and see if that helps (as a first step).

Comment: hmm full path to an image like "src/test.png" ?

Comment: Yes. put it under "src" and then add "test.png" in the "assets" list in . cli file.

Comment: again it's not in the dist directory. Image path is src/test.png , and I added "test.png" in assets array

Comment: hmm wierd even favicon.ico is not copied into the dist directory, I can see favicon on website but I guess that's because of cache

Comment: That is very strange indeed. You can try `ng build --env=prod` and see if that makes a difference. Or, you can reinstall @angular/cli and try again. I haven't seen problems like this. (Could be a very simple thing...)

Comment: I have already reinstalled angular-cli and tried to build in production and still not working but anyway thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I copied my project to other directory and run ng build and it's working now. I'm not sure why that happened but if somebody can explain that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

try to play with the location.
I think it should work.

```
<img src="../../assets/img/test.png" />

app-|
    |
    -components-|(../)
    |           |-navbar-|(../)
    |                    |-navbar.comp.html                           
    |               
    -assets-|
    |       |-img-|
    |             |-test.png
```